# WCF return class specialization

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've got the WCF web method `M` that returns the class `A`. The web method is configured to use the JSON serializer.

Now to the question: I've got the class `B` that is the immediate specialization of `A`. I want to return `B`, but the request fails if I do.

What do I need to do to make this work, if it's even possible?

This is essentially my problem in scribbled code:

```
[WebMethod]
A M();

public A M() {
   return new B(); // <-- no response on the client
} 

[DataContract]
class A { 
    [DataMember]
    bool Foo;
}

[DataContract]
class B : A {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to try would be:

```
[DataContract, KnownType(typeof(B))]
class A { 
    [DataMember]
    bool Foo;
}
```

Comment: That is brilliant! Such simple yet elegant solution! Thank you